# ClickOnce Strong-Name dependency signing

Tags: clickonce, strongname, assembly-signing

I have a windows application that that a lot of dependant DLLs.
When I publish this application it returns an error for one of the DLLs that it must be strongly signed in order to be marked as a prerequiste.
How can I resolve this problem?

Comment: Just in case you never solved this....is the dependant dll your dll or a 3rd party?  If it is yours, you need to get a key and configure it in your Signing properties of your project.  If it is a 3rd party dll, you will have to contact the vendor to see if they will sign it.